# Laravel Routes Issues when using wildcards

Tags: php, laravel

I have looked in quite a few places to no avail so I thought it was time to ask the experts.

I am playing about with laravel and I am having some issues with routing.

I have a cms of sorts and also a product catalogue, each of which uses no prefix to the pages.

A product might be 'example.com/my-product' and a page might be 'example.com/my-page'

In my routes I want to check if the url matches a page or a product or neither and then redirect to a specific controller/action depending on which it is.

currently I have

```
Route::any('/{slug}', function($slug) {
    $page = App\Models\Page::firstByAttributes(['slug' => $slug]);
    if($page) {
     // go to pagesController@find
    }
})->where('slug', '.*');
```

To differentiate between a page and a product is fine, I'll just pop an elseif after the if($page) for the product check but I am stumped as to how to get to the PagesController once I have determined that the url points to a page on the db.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Edit:

My Pages Controller:

```
class PagesController extends BaseController {

    public function find()
    {
        echo 'asdaasda'; die;
    }
}
```

I can get this to work after a fashion but its not what I want. I need the url to remain as it was and the PagesController to handle the processing and rendering of the page. The only way I can get it to work is by adding a Route::controller('pages', 'PagesController') to the routes file then modifying the find function to getFind but that just ends up with a url that looks like example.com/pages/find/ rather than the original url that might have been something along the line of example.com/about-us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Route::any('/{slug}', function($slug) {
    $page = App\Models\Page::firstByAttributes(['slug' => $slug]);
    if($page) {
      return Redirect::action('pagesController@find', array($page));
   }
})->where('slug', '.*');
```

You can also consider using route filters to achieve this in a slightly more readable way.

Comment: Thanks for this but its giving me a "unknown action" error yet there is a "find" action in the Pages controller.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your PagesController as well?

Comment: @SamParmenter change the pagesController with PagesController. I think it is case-sensitive.

Comment: I corrected that earlier and it doesn't make any difference i'm afraid. All the CMS systems I see just prepend pages to all the urls to get around this but thats a really dirty solution. I don't want /pages/about-us I just want /about-us

Comment: I have this: `Route::get('test/{token}', function($token){
      if($token == 'ok')
      {
        return  Redirect::action("LoginController@passwordReset");
      } 
})->where('token', '.*');` in my own project and it works properly... What else do you have in your routes.php ?

Comment: There is only a few admin routes in the routes.php file apart from the ones I have shown above. What does the url finish as in your above example. Does it finish as test/whatevertokenis or login/passwordreset?

Comment: When I type in `example.com/test/ok` it ends up on `example.com/login/passwordreset` . So it must be something with the PagesController itself. Have you tried putting a different controller there? Checked Namespaces?

Comment: I seem to have fixed it now. Yeah, what you have there is different to what I was after. Applying what I am after to your situation, I would want to visit test/{token} and use the loginController and password reset action but retain the test/{token} as my url.

Comment: I told a big lie, I haven't fixed it, the "fix" had the appearance of a solution but no more than that.

Comment: There is a way to do this, but it is dirty... in the `if($page){ return View::make('page', array('page' => $page)) } else { return View::make('post', array('post' => $page)); }` . It will clutter your routes.php file but it won't change your url in the browser

Comment: Will that allow the action of the PageController to process the request or does that bypass the controller and just hit the view?

Comment: It bypasses the controller and hits the view. It's not pretty, but it will work.

Comment: Hmm, I really need to be able to do more processing as pages can have templates that need to be set in the Controller. It seems a little odd that this can't be accomplished in a clean manner.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is super bad practice but the only way I can see to get around this issue is to do the following in routes.php.

```
$url = \URL::current();
$url = explode('/', $url);
$end = end($url);

if($page = App\Models\Page::firstByAttributes(['slug' => $end])) {
    Route::get('/'.$end, 'PagesController@find');
} elseif($product = App\Models\Product::firstByAttributes(['slug' => $end])) {
    Route::get('/'.$end, 'ProductsController@find');
}
```

This basically gets the final part of the url and then checks if we have a page with that url and add the route for that specific page, if not, it checks if we have a product that fits the url and adds the route for that product.

If anyone has a cleaner solution I would love to know. I can't imagine that laravel doesn't have a way of creating routes based on database pages without having to either prefix them all with something like "pages/page-url".